# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Tags: ios, mapkit, nsexception

i try to run my app, but i have got an exception thrown, in the console i have got this :

```
2011-05-05 00:18:50.984 myApp[2906:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x6b8b780> was mutated while being enumerated.(
    "<MyLocation: 0x6b67af0>",
    "<MyLocation: 0x6b19360>",
    "<MyLocation: 0x6b67a70>",
    "<MyLocation: 0x6b8d110>",
    "<MyLocation: 0x6b8d280>",
    "<MyLocation: 0x6b8ce50>",
    "<MyLocation: 0x6b8d660>"
)'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02915919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0272a5de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x029153d9 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 377
    3   myApp                          0x00005755 -[StationsSurLaCarteViewController requestFinished:] + 343
    4   myApp                          0x000195cb -[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished] + 171
    5   Foundation                          0x000abe9a __NSThreadPerformPerform + 251
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x028f6d7f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x028552cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x028547c6 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x02854280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x028541a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x02e8e2c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x02e8e38d GSEventRun + 115
    13  UIKit                               0x0033ab58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    14  myApp                          0x0000224c main + 102
    15  myApp                          0x000021dd start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)
```

i noticed that i got that since i try to use the annotations for my map view, help please, thx in advance :)

**EDIT**

this is my `for` loop which can make problems :

```
 for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {

           NSDictionary *stationEnCours=[array objectAtIndex:i];


           NSString *distance=[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"distance"];
           float lng = [[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"ssiphone_longitude"]   floatValue];
           float lat = [[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"ssiphone_latitude"] floatValue];
           NSString *ensStation=[stationEnCours objectForKey:@"ssiphone_enseigne"];

           location2D = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){ .latitude = lat, .longitude = lng };
           MyLocation *annotation=[[[MyLocation alloc]initWithName:ensStation distanceVersLaStation:distance coordinate:location2D]autorelease];
           [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
           MKCoordinateSpan span={latitudeDelta:0.2,longitudeDelta:0.2};
           MKCoordinateRegion region={location2D,span};
           [mapView setRegion:region];
           [self.view addSubview:mapView];
           }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given reason for your exception is "Collection ... was mutated while being enumerated". This means you tried to change an array within a `for( in )` loop, which is not allowed because it would change the objects that you are supposed to be enumerating. The end of the reason is a dump of the array which you were enumerating. It contains 7 `MyLocation` objects. If you look at the top of the call stack, you see that the exception occurred in your `-[StationsSurLaCarteViewController requestFinished:]` method. If you look through that method and find a place where you use fast enumeration, you should easily find your problem.

If you want to modify an array while using fast enumeration, there are two possibilities: keep track of all of the things you want to change (i.e. a list of indexes to remove) and make the changes after the loop, or do the enumeration over a *copy* of the array. Here is an example of the second method:

```
NSArray *copiedArray = [originalArray copy];
for(id theObject in copiedArray) {
    if([theObject shouldBeDeleted]) {
        [originalArray removeObject:theObject];
    }
}
[copiedArray release];
```

Comment: Hi, please take a look on my edit, i can't see what's wrong with the `for`loop, am i missing a memory management ?

Comment: Are you sure that loop is causing the crash? The one you are looking for should use the `for( in )` syntax, and changes the array named after the `in`. If that loop is the problem, then there is another loop running in a different thread which is also responsible.